# Convert my List<int> into a List<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `DropDownList` containing a range of ten years (from 2010 to 2020) created like such :

```
var YearList = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 5, ((DateTime.Now.Year + 3) - 2008) + 1));
ViewBag.YearList = YearList;
```

But here's my problem, I wish to **have a default value selected and keep this value when I submit** my information and I wish to use the type `List<SelectListItem>` for it, since its more practical.

Once in this type I will simply do as such to keep a selected value:

```
foreach (SelectListItem item in list)
            if (item.Value == str)
                item.Selected = true;
```

How may I convert my `List<int>` into a `List<SelectListItem>` ?

Comment: You dont set `item.Selected = true`! You bind to a model property. See my comments to your last question

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try converting it using Linq:

```
List<SelectListItem> item = YearList.ConvertAll(a =>
                {
                    return new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = a.ToString(),
                        Value = a.ToString(),
                        Selected = false
                    };
                });
```

Then the item will be the list of SelectListItem

Answer (score 21):

There is now an even cleaner way to do this:

```
SelectList yearSelectList = new SelectList(YearList, "Id", "Description");
```

Where Id is the name of the list item's value, and Description is the text. If you like you can add a parameter after this to specify the selected item. All you gotta do it pass in the ICollection that you wish to convert to a select list!

In you view you do this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.YearListItemId,
                        yearSelectList as SelectList, "-- Select Year --",
                        new { id = "YearListItem", @class= "form-control", @name= 
"YearListItem" })
```

Comment: This should be the answer - Excellent Answer! ( & Clean!!)

Comment: The question explicit asks for List<int>. There is no "Id" nor "Description" for List<int>.

Comment: Wow.. where do you live fella? I've got to buy you a drink

Answer (score 14):

You can use LINQ to convert the items from a `List<int>` into a `List<SelectListItem>`, like so:

```
var items = list.Select(year => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = year.ToString(),
    Value = year.ToString()
});
```