# Populate select tag razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Core MVC project.

I have a view model which contains a list as:

```
public class CampaignViewModel
{
    public IList<Agency> Agencies { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller, I assign that list like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
    var agencies = await _agenciesService.GetAgenciesAsync();
    var model = new CampaignViewModel { Agencies = agencies };
}
```

`GetAgenciesAsync` method:

```
public async Task<IList<Agency>> GetAgenciesAsync()
{
    return await _db.Agencies
                    .Include(a => a.Address)
                    .Include(pc => pc.PrimaryContact)
                    .Include(ac => ac.AlternateContact)
                    .ToListAsync();
}
```

Agency model class:

```
public class Agency
{
    public int AgencyId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    ...
}
```

Then in my razor view, I want to render it as:

```
 @model Lib.ViewModels.Campaigns.CampaignViewModel
<select asp-for="Agencies" asp-items="Model.Agencies" class="form-select"></select>
```

When I try to run the project, I get an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project.Lib.Models.Agency>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>'.
> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How can I solve that? Regards

Comment: Please provide the code for CampaignViewModel @Demian

Comment: Sorry, the CampaignViewModel is the first one I posted. Corrected @JyothishBhaskaran

Comment: Please provide GetAgenciesAsync() method also @Demian

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667310/convert-my-listint-into-a-listselectlistitem @Demian hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the error indicates,asp-items expects type of `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` instead of `IEnumerable<Agency>`

You could try as below:

```
<select asp-for="Agencies" asp-items="Model.Agencies.Select(x=>new SelectListItem() { Text=x.Name,Value=x.AgencyId.ToString()})" class="form-select"></select>
```

And I tried to pass the viewmodel form controller to view :

```
var vm = new CampaignViewModel() { Agencies = new List<Agency>() { new Agency() { AgencyId = 1, Name = "SomeName" }, new Agency() { AgencyId = 2, Name = "AnotherName" } } };
```

The Result:

[image]

I don't know why the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'Select'` occored in your project(I just created an empty MVC project and it works well,don't need refer other namespaces)

Maybe you could try pass the selectListitems from controller to View as below

in controller:

```
ViewBag.Select = vm.Agencies.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Name, Value = x.AgencyId.ToString() }).ToList();
```

in View:

```
asp-items="(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Select"
```

Comment: I tried but apparently `Select` does not exist on my razor view. Did you import something? it says: Cannot resolve symbol 'Select', note: I'm talking about select linq

Comment: I didn't import anything,just tried with an empty MVC project,maybe you could try with viewbag,I've updated the answer,If you still have problems, it may help if you could upload your project to github

Comment: Ohh, it works now, but why the select is it showing as a list instead as a dropdown? I have another select tags and they are displayed as a dropdown

Comment: because you bind the selected value with CampaignViewModel.Agencies,mvc would add mutipule property which allows you choose serval options in your select tag ,If you create another property in your view model like public int AgencyId { get; set; }  and modify the codes in your view asp-for="AgencyId" it would look like a dropdown

Answer (score 0):

try to this:
Create.cshtml

`@model CampaignViewModel`